# How can I delete bytes from a file with a hexeditor on ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, reverse-engineering

I have a number of binary files that I need to remove sections of content from. Most of these are dumps from HTTP requests that I want to manually extract some payloads from for testing.

I have always used `hexedit` to modify parts of binary files, but am realizing this cannot actually delete a byte from a file. Seems as though hexcurses also has this limitation.

Is there anything on ubuntu that I can use `vim` style commands like `x` to just delete a byte from a binary file?

Comment: https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2232

Comment: Lots of decent hex editors available for Linux. I often use `bvi` (Binary Vi) for this purpose.  See http://bvi.sourceforge.net/   The `radare2` project also has a good hex editor.